# Replicating calculated fee at checkout function to WP admin

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I've successfully implemented a function that calculates warehouse storage fees to be charged on a product once it goes through checkout. This is calculated by first checking ACF fields - first if it should be charged, and if so, to calculate storage fees from the date (also an ACF field).

```
//Add storage fee to a reservation at checkout if applicable 

add_action('woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'add_storage_fees');
function add_storage_fees(){
    if (is_admin() && !defined('DOING_AJAX')) {
            return;
    }
    foreach ( $cart = WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
        // gets the product object
        $product = $cart_item['data'];
        // gets the product prices
        $checkbox = $product->get_meta('charge_for_storage');
        if (!empty($checkbox)){
            $landed_date = $product->get_meta('landed_date');
            $now = time(); 
            $date_landed = strtotime($landed_date);
            $datediff = $now - $date_landed;
            $days = round($datediff / (60 * 60 * 24));
            $weeks = ( $days / 7 );
            if( $weeks > 1){
                $quantity = $cart_item['quantity'];
            }       
    }   
    $storage_cost += (($weeks * 0.25)* $quantity);
}  
if( $storage_cost > 0.1 ){  
WC()->cart->add_fee(__('Storage fee', 'txtdomain'), $storage_cost, true, 'Reduced rate');
    }
}
```

My struggle is now replicating this function to be automatically implemented in WP admin when manually creating an order for a customer - to be calculated when hitting 'recalculate' or whatever is easiest, really. I can't get it to work at all. This is my code so far:

```
// Add storage fee to applicable reservations in order admin

add_action('woocommerce_order_after_calculate_totals', 'damo_apply_storage_cost_admin');
function damo_apply_storage_cost_admin($order) {
    
        //$order = wc_get_order($order_id);
        foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item_id => $item ) {
            
            $product  = $item->get_product();
            $checkbox = $product->get_meta('charge_for_storage');

            if (!empty($checkbox)){
                $landed_date = $product->get_meta('landed_date');
                $now = time(); 
                $date_landed = strtotime($landed_date);
                $datediff = $now - $date_landed;
                $days = round($datediff / (60 * 60 * 24));
                $weeks = ( $days / 7 );
                    if( $weeks > 1){
                $quantity = $cart_item['quantity'];
            }       
    }   
    $storage_cost += (($weeks * 0.25)* $quantity);
}  
if( $storage_cost > 0.1 ){  

                $fee = new WC_Order_Item_Fee();
                $fee->set_name('Storage fee');
                $fee->set_amount($storage_cost);
                $fee->set_tax_class('Reduced rate');
                $fee->set_tax_status('taxable');
                $fee->set_total($storage_cost);

                $order->add_item($fee);
                $order->calculate_totals();
                $order->save();
            }
}
```